# SVN only reading first word of commit message?

Tags: svn, commit, fedora

Normally when I commit things to our repository, I do
svn ci *file1 file2 file3 etc* -m "this is a message about the changes I'm committing."

I'm currently working on a different computer (which happens to be running Fedora instead of my usual Ubuntu), and when I do this, it balks, saying

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: '/home/[path]/[word]' is not under version control
```

where [word] is the second word of my commit message. 
(e.g., in the above example ("this is a message..."), *"is"*).

I don't suppose SVN works differently in Fedora?
What could be causing this problem, and what do I need to do to use the -m flag here?

Comment: Hmmm, try single quotes instead of double?

Comment: The command `svn` actually being a poorly written shell script could cause this. What does `less \`which svn\`` say?

Comment: TheZ: Sorry, I do in fact use double quotes, but both variants produce this behavior.
@PascalCuoq: /usr/bin/svn

Comment: I doubt `less \`which svn\`` says "/usr/bin/svn".

Comment: @PascalCuoq, rather, that's what which svn says.
it's a binary file, so I don't think you want the result of lessing it ;)

Comment: `which` tells you where `csh` would find the command.  If you're using `bash`, do `type svn` instead.  Also, what happens if you specify the path to `svn` explicitly?  I.e.run `/usr/bin/svn ci ...` instead of just `svn ci ...`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Instead, of that. Do `which svn` first. This will tell you the command, or if in fact `svn` is an alias or a function. If it's a file, then the OP should do `file /location/of/svn` to see what type of file it is. If it's a binary executable, the output of the `file` command will say that. If it's a shell script, the `file` command will report that too.

Comment: @ottomeister
`svn is a function
svn () 
{ 
    op=$1;
    shift;
    us="hrilab";
    if [ ${op} == "ci" ]; then
        us="nobody";
    fi;
    /usr/bin/svn ${op} --username ${us} $*
}`

Comment: @DavidW. /usr/bin/svn: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped

Comment: /usr/bin/svn ci [file] -m [message] works correctly...

Comment: @ottomeister so is it this function that is causing the problem?
I don't see what it is doing that would be causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. If I try to commit directly at the terminal, then `-m` works fine. But if I try to commit using a script then it would only take the first word from the comment string. Even using the `--non-interactive` option did not help.

Finally as a work around, in the script I am creating a temporary file with the comment string in it and then using `--file` option to supply the comment for the commit command.

```
echo ${COMMENT[$i]} > .tempistan
if [ -n "${FILES_TO_COMMIT[$i]}" ]; then
    svn_cmd="/usr/bin/svn --non-interactive commit --file .tempistan ${FILES_TO_COMMIT[$i]}"
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In standard Unix commands, the parameters should go **BEFORE** the file names:

```
$ svn ci -m "This is a message about the changes I'm committing." file1 file2 file3 etc.
```

It might not be a difference in Subversion between the two systems, but the shell being used. The shell parses the command, and sends the files and parameters to the command. This way, the shell handles file expansion.

Try putting the `-m` parameter before the file names. Make sure you use quotes around your commit message.

Comment: Tried that, but there is no change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Comments with `-m` should go first...

```
$ svn ci -m "changes" file1 file2 file3
```

Comment: Tried that, but there is no change in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that svn was a function that called /usr/bin/svn while not allowing committers to use the computer's shared username when checking things in, as an accountability measure.

It is still annoying, but /usr/bin/svn can be used, and the committer can still type a message into nano after not using the -m flag.

Thanks to @David_W for suggesting "type svn", which revealed the function in question.